# Exact meaning of "consists of"

Tags: terminology

What does *consists of* mean exactly, say in *an arithmetic progression of length $n$ consists of prime numbers*? Are there only prime numbers or must there be at least one prime number in the progression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an arithmetic progression of length 3 consists of square numbers, it means that all of its 3 terms are perfect squares.

Answer (score 4):

'consists of' in mathematics means precisely what it means in ordinary language use. If thing $A$ consists of $B$ then it means that the things in $A$ are all $B$. So, if an arithmetic progression consists of prime numbers then all elements in the arithmetic progression are prime numbers.